# IOS notification don't show image

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

For Flutter iOS
I connected firebasemessag. APNS is also connected, it is also working. But it doesn't show pictures on IOS. For this I added Notification Service Extension as a target. If I select Objective-C code, it gives an error when building. I can't figure out how to add the relevant part of Firebemessaging to it if I choose Swift Codes?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use `HTTP v1` api

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

follow the above link to migrate to `HTTP v1`

here is payload which will show image in notification

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-image

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"your token will be here",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Sparky says hello!",
     },
     "android":{
       "notification":{
         "image":"https://foo.bar/pizza-monster.png"
       }
     },
     "apns":{
       "payload":{
         "aps":{
           "content-available" : 1
           "mutable-content":1
         }
       },
       "fcm_options": {
           "image":"https://foo.bar/pizza-monster.png"
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "image":"https://foo.bar/pizza-monster.png"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

and with `flutter_local_notifications` plugin

```
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
'channel_id', // id
'High Importance Notifications', // title
description:
  'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
importance: Importance.high,
);

var iosNotificationDetails =
          IOSNotificationDetails(attachments: <IOSNotificationAttachment>[
        IOSNotificationAttachment(yourPicturePath),
      ]);

      var androidNotificationDetails =
          AndroidNotificationDetails(channel.id, channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              enableLights: true,
              icon: "ic_f",
              playSound: true,
              priority: Priority.high,
              importance: Importance.max,
              styleInformation: BigPictureStyleInformation(
                FilePathAndroidBitmap(yourPicturePath),
              ));

var notificationDetail = NotificationDetails(
        iOS: iosNotificationDetails, android: androidNotificationDetails);
    Random random = Random();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        random.nextInt(10000),
        "title",
        "body",
        notificationDetail);
```